# Pasting non-ascii (utf8) into remote urxvt terminal

Tags: terminal, unicode, rxvt, paste

For pasting text, in urxvt/rxvt-unicode one can use <kbd>middle button</kbd> to paste PRIMARY selection.

I can do such Mouse-Middle-Click paste in my local urxvt terminal and even a remote server, in Chinese/utf8 strings. EG if I run `date` under `LANG=zh_CN.utf8` environment and I'll get:

```
$ date
2023年 03月 18日 星期六 15:01:11 EDT
```

I can then mouse ***select*** the Chinese/utf8 string `星期六` and Mouse-Middle-Click ***paste*** into my urxvt terminal (after my echo), like:

```
$ echo 星期六
星期六
```

in my local urxvt terminal and even a remote server. However, if I ssh into my other local machines, or my Oracle cloud then try the same approach, instead of `echo 星期六` showing up on my command line, I'm getting:

[image]

if I select the whole `echo 星期六`, and past into the remote session, then it'll work, for either my local machines or my Oracle cloud server.

Here is the screen-cast to illustrate it:

[image]

EG

- the Chinese/utf8 strings cannot be pasted into my remote urxvt terminal normally.
- however if there are some leading normal ascii characters before the Chinese/utf8 string, then the whole thing can be pasted in normally.

All my environment are configured the same across all of them, So I'm thinking there must be something odd with my configuration which works only locally but not remotely.

(My local machines and Oracle cloud server displays Chinese/utf8 strings/filenames just fine though.)

**UPDATE:** more debug info

```bash
$ locale 
LANG=zh_CN.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_PAPER="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_NAME="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN.utf8"
LC_ALL=

$ locale charmap
UTF-8

$ grep '^set.*meta' ~/.inputrc
set meta-flag on
set input-meta On
set output-meta On
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Is it only the shell that's misbehaving, or also other apps (e.g. text editors)? Check the output of `locale`, it should look reasonable. Check the output of `locale charmap`, it should say `UTF-8`. Check your shell's config. Is your shell `bash`? If so, `.inputrc` should contain things like `set input-meta on` and `set output-meta on`.

Comment: I've updated my OP to include answers to all your questions, @egmont, thanks. Basically all are as expected. And, BINGO! it **is** _only_ the shell that's misbehaving (yes my shell is bash), using a text editor, pasting Chinese/utf8 strings works just fine!

Comment: Okay so it's obviuosly a bash thing, then, but I have no idea what exactly. Maybe try comparing `/etc/inputrc` and `.inputrc` on the two systems, looking for other differences. Also check bash's version, maybe the remote one is an ancient version that was buggy? But I'm just shooting in the dark.